# How create database and tables, and fill them with data? I got error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to create a database inside its table and fill it with data.
To do this, I write the following code, but it turns out an error:

```
<?php

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("categories.json"), true)['categories'];
foreach ($json as $elem) {
    print_r($elem);
}

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

$sql = "DROP DATABASE cats";
mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$sql = "CREATE DATABASE cats";
mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$sql = "CREATE TABLE cats.categories (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, id_category INT, name VARCHAR(255), alias VARCHAR(255))";
mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE cats.category_child (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, id_category INT, id_child INT)";
mysqli_query($link, $sql);

foreach ($json as $elem) {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO cats.categories (id_category, name, alias) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iss", $elem['id'], $elem['name'], $elem['alias']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    var_dump(mysqli_error($link));
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

}    

?>
```

`var_dump(mysqli_error($link))` prints: `string(37) "Table 'cats.categories' doesn't exist"`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: . . Check the errors when you execute SQL statements.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you help me fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On second thought, this doesn't work:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_category INT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    alias VARCHAR(255)
);
```

I think the error is pretty self-explanatory:

> Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

However, it might not be totally clear what to do for someone learning SQL.  You can phrase it as:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_category INT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    alias VARCHAR(255)
);
```

By the way, kudos for using parameters!